# Write a file to a Windows remote location from Unix

Tags: java, windows, unix, fileoutputstream

My application is deployed on a Unix machine and trying to write a file to remote Windows location. Instead of writing the file to the remote location, app is writing it to the Server's location (**Unix**) where the app is deployed to.

Any idea what could be going wrong? I have tried to put the location in the following ways:

```
1. FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\windows_server_name\\anyDir\\filename.xml"))

2. FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\windows_server_name\\anyDir\\filename.xml"))
```

It always creates the file at app server's location with the name of the remote location's address. e.g

"**\\windows_server_name\anyDir\filename.xml**". It creates a file like this.

Answer (score 0):

To connect and write to your server you need a `URL` to connect to over ftp something like

```
URL url = new URL ("ftp://username:password@windows_server_name/anyDir/filename.xml");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Actually the remote Windows location had to be mapped (mounted) to AIX server. And I had to just use the mapped location instead of directly accessing the remote Windows machine.

I did not make any code changes and was able to write the file in the same way as shown above in the question.

Thanks for your inputs all.

Comment: If you cannot mount shares (eg. because you're not root-user), you can still use program `smbclient` to transfer files.